# Can't keep div and background positioned correclty with different screen sizes

Tags: css, html, background, positioning

Title says most of it. I have a div container that holds all the site divs, and a background. I'm just trying to make the background "stretch" correctly if you take the screen out of max or if it is on a different monitor size/pixels (there is a computer at work that doesn't fill the screen, but my widescreen and MOST others it does). Also, if you take out of max screen it cuts off parts of the site, and I don't know why.

Relevant CSS:

```
body {

font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
color: lightsteelblue;
font-size: 14px;
background-image: url("../images/hardcoregames-bg-final.png"); 
-webkit-background-size: 100%; /*for webKit*/
-moz-background-size: 100%; /*Mozilla*/
-o-background-size: 100%; /*opera*/
background-size: 100%; /*generic*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top left;
background-color: #222;
}
#maindiv {
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#navigation {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
/*left: 360px;
margin: 0px;*/
left: 50%;
margin-left: -325px;
z-index: 10000;
width: 650px;
height: 100px;
padding: 50px 20px;
background-color: transparent;
float: left;
}
```

And my markup is simple:

```
<body>
    <div id="maindiv">
        <div id="navigation">
            <img src="images/hardcoregames-logo1.png"></img> 
        </div>
        <div id="other divs just like navigation but positioned in different spots">
            stuff
        </div>
    </div>
<body>
```

to see it in action: [Site](http://hardcoregamesusa.com)
I've tried using 100% for both width and height in background-size, but that made it worse with height not on auto. I've tried putting the main div as absolute. I've tried using background-size to cover. To add, I've seen other things on here for this, but none of the ideas I've read worked so far, and I don't want the background fixed, the image is as large as the main page is so I want it that way.

P.S.
Please as a reminder the "maindiv" is also being cut when getting out of maximize screen on IE at least as well. I added that issue with the background one because I think they both have to do with my width/height, but then again I really don't know. The code I posted works correctly, until you size the screen small enough, then scroll right. Also in about the same size IE screen, you can't go all the way left on the site anymore, its cut off.

Images showing scrolled all the way right and left. Scrolled right, it cuts off a good 1/3 of the page. Scrolled right, the bg doesn't fill in all the way and it looks dumb. [pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Hxw.jpg)

Comment: I got what's the problem here, your navigation is positioned absolute and that is causing that cut, when your browser is resized inshort, your markup and positioning is wrong

Comment: All of the divs in the relative, "maindiv" are absolute. Don't they have to be for me to have the position they are in, and since theyre in a relative pos container?

Comment: you are using negative margins, you've to fix up many things

Comment: With a left 50%, so it centers, unless there is another clean way to do that per pixels/screen?

Comment: there are many simpler ways to achieve that

Comment: Im not saying there isn't I'm just wondering what those ways are. :D

Comment: you can do as simple as this, you can do more simpler but I didn't had much time to go so far have a look http://jsfiddle.net/Hde6Y/1/

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to try it tomorrow night. I'll post if I have any questions though.

Comment: Could you take time to explain it? It worked, and from what it looks like you're just using margins and relative position so its always correct placement?

Comment: You should learn css positioning

Comment: I know some of the basics, I'm just trying to get an explanation of what you did, plus others coming here that don't know can learn a little as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setup is what fixed the "cut off" of the web page when taking out of maximum screen. [Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/Hde6Y/1/)
Thanks @Mr. Alien

For the background; on my research, and should have been obvious, you can't "dynamically" change the background as the person changes the window size of, say, IE in just CSS. This fixed the background to work per initial screen size as far as I can see.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("../images/hardcoregames-bg-final.png"); 
    -webkit-background-size: 100% auto; /*for webKit*/
    -moz-background-size: 100% auto; /*Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: 100% auto; /*opera*/
    background-size: 100% auto; /*generic*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-color: #222;
}
```

If I'm wrong on this, please correct me. But the best I can get it to do is size the background initially and that's it. I suppose some javascript or, better yet, jquery can fix this as it's an issue with it working dynamically. I'll keep this answer open for now and comment please if I'm wrong. Don't want the wrong message going out.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly...

create a background image large enough for the widest standard screen resolution (2560) and smallest screen ratio (4:3). Creating the background in size 2560 x 1920 and setting 'background-size: 100% auto' should have it fill the background on all monitors without any issue.

Comment: I hope this isn't what I have to do, beacuse too much time went in that background, but as a last resort I will do this.

Answer (score 1):

Issue could be with background-size. If the computer at your work was using Internet Explore 8 or below, background-size is not supported. If this is issue I can explain a work around, let me know.

EDIT: Was not IE 8, try below.

```
html { 
  background: url('../images/hardcoregames-bg-final.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: One of them is IE 8, but I'm pretty sure the one I'm referring to isn't. It's funny because IE 8, if I remember correctly, shows up just fine lol. Although, I had specific width height when I checked 8, but was trying to fix the issue for the newer windows 7 computer. The monitor is actually the same size, but I'm pretty sure the pixel is more "fine", or however you would say it.

Comment: Can't have fixed background. Cuts the bg in about half if I do.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `background-position: top left;`  and it'll be solved. This causes your logo to always be on the top left of the window irrespective of the window size

Comment: Er..Sorry i thought you were worrying about "logo" being overlapped with the navigation bar..So your problem is with the background image huh

Comment: Try `background-size:contain` instead. This should fix it...Report the output

Comment: That made it disappear completely. I did try contain with some other stuff before and it made it waaaaay too small.

Comment: I am also worried about that though....although removing background-position didn't solve it.

Comment: Really! That's the only reason behind the floating logo according to me. What did it show after removing it? did it remain unchanged?

Comment: yeah it was still on top of the navigation when you resize the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This style can keep your background stretch in any different resolution:

```
body, html
{
  font-size:14px !important;
  color: lightsteelblue;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("../images/hardcoregames-bg-final.png"); 
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-color: #222;
  background: no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Trying to stay away from "fixed" positions for the bg, because it cuts out almost have the bottom of the background. I appreciate it though, as I tried this earlier and it did work. Just can't have such a small bg, and it wouldn't scroll all the way down.